# How to get all marklogic search records in single Rest API call?

Tags: search, marklogic

I am using Marklogic rest Api to search records in the marklogic server. I need to get all the results in a single call. As the default pagelength is set to 10, I am able to retrieve only 10 records if there is no specific mentione. Is there a way to retrieve all the records in a single marklogic rest api call?

Answer (score 1):

*To answer the specific question:*

Please have a look at the options related to the endpoint.

[v1/search](https://docs.marklogic.com/10.0/REST/GET/v1/search)

You will notice 2 of interest:

-`start`

-`pageLength`

This is probably what you are looking for.

*However*....
You want to get *all* of the results. Is that 10? 200? 2 million?
It is likely that after a certain number of results, you will either (1) run out of memory or (2) time out. Pagination on RESTful services allows you to return your results in batches - allowing you t still get all results, but do it in a way that plays nicely with available resources.

Comment: I have tried these two params with the request.  I am having around 10000 of requests and the response is not of much size. So I want to fetch all the records at once. As the default pageLength is 10, if I remove these params from the query, I am only getting 10 records.

Comment: ïf I remove the params,from the query, I am only getting 10.." well, that makes sense.. the docs state that the default is 10, so removing the params would result in .. 10..

Docs as in the link provided: "..The maximum number of results to return in this request. Default: 10,...

Comment: Yes, is there anyway for me to disable the default limit and retrieve 10000 results in single instance?

Comment: Hmm.. Good question.   You should really ask that as a separate question. However, for a quick answer:  You could probably set a new default in query options:  https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/appendixa#id_75920

You could also set the params at runtime via a rewrite rule 
https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/XMLrewriter#id_15282

Comment: :) I might not know the count of all the records in the first place. In order to know the count need to make another call to marklogic  which might be extra overhead. 
I cannot have any default option and need retrieve all the record in a single call, it can be 1000, 5000, 10000 or more than that.

Comment: Getting everything at once won't scale nor is fastest. Do a call with pageLength zero first to get total, then proceed with parallel calls with pageLength 10, 100 or 1000 to gather all results, accumulate what you received client side.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the settings for the snippets. The default values might limit the number of responses which is misleading but in fact you are telling the search engine to return fewer responses.
For that you need to use a structured search in which you define an xml or json search query and using it in the body of the post request.
Here is a json structured query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "queries": [
      {
        "term-query": {
          "text": [
            "text to be searched"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "options": {
    "transform-results": {
      "apply": "snippet",
      "preferred-matches": "",
      "max-matches": 10,
      "max-snippet-chars": 10000,
      "per-match-tokens": 10
    }
  }
}
```

Play with the three attributes `max-matches, max-snippet-chars, per-match-tokens` to tune the number of responses.
`max-matches` indicates for each document how many snippets to be returned at most.
`per-match-tokens` indicates how many words in each snippet surround the main searched text at most.
`max-snippet-chars` is the overall number of characters in all returned snippets at most. Use a large number here.
More details in MarkLogic help page:
"Modifying Your Snippet Results" in chapter 8 (Search Customization Using Query Options) [Link](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/query-options#id_58295)
"Example: Simple Structured Search" in Chapter 4 (Searching Using Structured Queries) [Link](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/structured-query#id_94406)